# Microsoft excel calculates the time based on their own Excel Serial Number which prevents to calculate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

Microsoft excel calculates the time based on their own Excel Serial Number which prevents to calculate the split seconds. Suppose a time format 56:23.34 (mm:ss:00) format where last "00" is split second, is passed through any excel function it omits the split seconds and reads only the second until two digit. Is there any other method to tackle this so that we can make calculation of split seconds as well?

For example, an athlete who ran certain distance recorded his time as 34:23.37 and 23:45:12 in mm:sss.00 (minute:second.SplitSecond) format . How to calculate the average of this time?

Comment: `Average` will work. The average of `01:00.54` and `00:58.70` is `00:59.62`

Answer (score 0):

to do this format the cells with a custom time format "mm:ss.000". Once this is done it will show the split seconds in the cells. then just use =AVERAGE(A1:B1)